# Почему виджет не виден в списке виджетов?

Tags: android

Внутри `<application>` в манифесте

```
    <receiver android:name=".WidgetProvider" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget" />
    </receiver>
```

xml/widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="25dp"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="2400000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget"/>
```

layout/widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dlp.recircle.MainView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
</dlp.recircle.MainView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле `xml/widget.xml` поменяйте строку :

```
xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

на строку:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```